# CodeIgniter Form Validation Error Redirect to section page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a page divided by sections, and last section have a form contact.

My code form:

> ```
> <section id="contact">
> <div class="contact_form">
>         <span class="form_settings">
>             <?php
>             $this->load->helper("form");
>             //echo $msg;
>             //echo validation_errors();
>
>             echo form_open("main/send_email");
>             echo form_label("", "nome");
>             $data = array(
>                 "placeholder" => "Nome:",
>                 "class" => "form_settings",
>                 "name" => "nome",
>                 "id" => "nome",
>                 "value" => set_value("nome")
>             );
>             echo form_input($data);
>             echo form_error('nome');
>
>
>             echo form_label("", "email");
>             $data = array(
>                 "placeholder" => "Email:",
>                 "class" => "form_settings",
>                 "name" => "email",
>                 "id" => "email",
>                 "value" => set_value("email")
>             );
>             echo form_input($data);
>             echo form_error('email');
>
>
>             echo form_label("", "msg");
>             $data = array(
>                 "placeholder" => "Mensagem:",
>                 "class" => "form_settings",
>                 "name" => "msg",
>                 "id" => "msg",
>                 "value" => set_value("msg")
>             );
>             echo form_textarea($data);
>             echo form_error('msg');
>
>
>             echo form_submit("submit", "Enviar", "class='form_settings'");
>             echo form_close();
>             ?>
>
>         </span>
>     </div>
> </section>
> ```

My Controller have a function send_email() :

```
public function send_email() {
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("nome", "Nome:", "required|alpha|xss_clean");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email:", "required|valid_email|xss_clean");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("msg", "Mensagem:", "required|xss_clean");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('main/contactPage#contact');
    } else {

        $this->load->library("email");
        $this->email->from(set_value("email"), set_value("nome"), set_value("msg"));
        $this->email->to("xxx@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject("Mensagem");
        $this->email->message(set_value("msg"));

        $this->email->send();
        $data["msg"] = "Email enviado com sucesso!";
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        redirect('main/contactPage#contact', $data);

        }
    }
```

If form error, it redirects to section page but doesn't show the validation errors.
If correct form, it redirects to section page but doesn't show the value of $data.

Any solution for this?

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT #2:**
After racking my brain, this is what I've come up with. If the form validation is FALSE, then you check for each individual validation error, and if they exist, set a flash data item. Then redirect, and echo out the flash data if it is set. Below is the updated code.

*controller*

```
public function send_email() { 
    $this->load->library("form_validation"); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("nome", "Nome:", "required|alpha|xss_clean"); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email:", "required|valid_email|xss_clean"); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("msg", "Mensagem:", "required|xss_clean"); 

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            // Set the flashdata that will be preserved for only the next server request
            if (form_error('nome')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('nome-failed','Your error message here');
            }
            if (form_error('email')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('email-failed','Your error message here');
            }
            if (form_error('email')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg-failed','Your error message here');
            }

            // Redirect to the contact section
            redirect('main/contactPage#contact');

    } else {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('nome'));
        $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Mensagem');
        $this->email->message($this->input->post('msg'));

        $this->email->send();       

        if ($this->email->send() === TRUE) {
            // Set the flashdata that will be preserved for only the next server request
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Email enviado com sucesso!');

            // Redirect to the contact section
            redirect('main/contactPage#contact');
        }
    } 
}
```

*view*

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper("form");

    // Test to see if the var is set before you try to echo it so you won't get an error
    if ( isset( $this->session->flashdata('success') ) ) {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
    };
    if ( isset( $this->session->flashdata('nome-failed') ) ) { 
        echo $this->session->flashdata('nome-failed');
    };
    if ( isset( $this->session->flashdata('email-failed') ) ) { 
        echo $this->session->flashdata('email-failed');
    };

    if ( isset( $this->session->flashdata('msg-failed') ) ) {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('msg-failed');
    };

    echo form_open("main/send_email");
```

**EDIT #1:**
I missed a part in the controller, specifically, you cannot redirect, and expect validation errors to follow. All that you end up doing is basically reloading the form from scratch. So you need to load the view, under the `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {` branch, in order to see any form validation errors generated by the form validation rules you have set above. I fixed my controller code above to reflect that. The view code in the form will stay the same though. [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller) is the relevant page from the CI user guide showing you what you need to structure your code like.

**Original Answer:**
From what I can gather (your formatting for the controller is borked), it does not look like you are actually inputting values into the sendmail function. You can do that by calling the `$this->input->post();` function in CI.

I don't believe you can pass data on a redirect (at least I've never been able to, nor have I found such documentation for CI that suggests that), so you should test if the email sent successfully, and if so, reload the view with your `$msg` variable set with the success message, so it can be displayed.

You've also commented out the part of your view that would display the form validation error or send success data. But I suspect you were getting a PHP undefined variable error before you commented them, so check to see if the var is set first, then echo if it is. Example below.

Comment: my problem isn't sending the email, because it is working! And the way you say, I get 4 emails with the samething...

My problem is to redirect the section #contact. 

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
redirect('main/contactPage#contact'); 
    } else {
...
}

This works, but the validation forms don't appear!
The samething for msg

About undefined variable msg, you're right :)

Comment: I fixed my controller logic. You can't use a redirect and have validation errors follow. See the Edit above. And if the way you were sending emails works, great, disregard my recommendations on that.

Comment: It isn't possible to redirect for <section  id="contact"> ??

I know what do you say, i know if i load the view with the form i have the form errors. The problem begin when i show total page, composed for 5 views and I want to redirect for <section  id="contact">, this section located in view contact.

Comment: I've put up another crack at the code. I haven't tested is myself, so you'll have to let me know if it works out.

Comment: you are correct that you cannot redirect, and if you are using ajax then flash won't help either. Here's a walkthrough of using ajax forms w/ codeigniter that I wrote that should get you on the right track: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Answer (score 0):

Once there is a change in the controller file, the validation message of CI does not work at all. You have to use the session. It works only for messages coming from a direct load of view pages within the same controller.